# jQuery ajax success function inside success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call an ajax function inside the success function of a function.
This is my code:

```
success: function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php?subtype=3",
        data: "page=1",
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery(".data").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 150);
            jQuery(".outer-data").css({'background': 'url("ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%'});
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            jQuery("#container_cat").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                jQuery(".outer-data").css({'background': 'none'});
                jQuery("#container_cat").html(msg);
            });
        }
        // ...
    });
}
```

Even though I get the response in Firebug console from

```
jQuery("#container_cat").html(msg);
```

I don't get any output in the document.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is `msg`? From where you get this?

Comment: Looks like msg is a JSON object here.. Check in the console section to see the contents of msg.. May be it is msg.d  or something..

Comment: yes, please post the msg. you should probably parse the msg data before setting the HTML... maybe msg is not a string (maybe its inserting something that is not visible but is set in the source)?

Comment: Where is `jQuery("#container_cat").ajaxComplete` getting called from? It is already 'success'

Comment: Also, you may want to look into pipe(), when(), then() for this paradigm (look at Deferred objects in jQuery API). It would make your code a bit cleaner and more manageable.

Comment: I think you are missing (or omitted?) some braces, so I've suggested an edit -- hope it helps.

Comment: msg is a JSON object and its contents are corrent in the console. My problem is that its content is generated only in the console and not in the document.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php?subtype=3",
        data: "page=1",
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery(".data").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 150);
            jQuery(".outer-data").css({'background': 'url("ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%'});
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            jQuery(".outer-data").css({'background': 'none'});
            jQuery("#container_cat").html(msg);
        }
        // ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the problem is that you are calling the ajaxComplete() function inside the success function. You dont need to use ajaxComplete inside success function as success function will only be executed when the ajax request is completed and succeeded. So theres no sense of using ajaxComplete inside it. 
For reference : [ajaxComplete docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp) 
You can use ajaxComplete before success function.